# on click event over a modal with various pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal, with a series of pictures on it. My idea is that the user clicks on the picture he/she chooses and a message appear on top of the image saying "you selected this image". So far, I can make the message appear only on the first image, because I gave it in CSS the same margins at the first picture... Is it a way to avoid this and having each image have its own message without having to write so much CSS? as well this modal will replicate various times in the website, with more pictures, depending on the situation, so I am looking for a way to avoid too much coding.

```js
.img-thumbnail {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /*para hover:*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.img_description {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 128, 68);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.localizaciones {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*//para hover:*/
  position: relative;
}

.localizacionHover {
  position: absolute;
}

.img-thumbnail:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```css
function showTextThumbnail() {
    var text = document.querySelector(".img_description");
    text.style["display"] = "block";
}

var el = document.querySelector(".img-thumbnail");
el.addEventListener("click", showTextThumbnail, false)
```

```html
<div id="central-bottom" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Cerrar" class="close">X</a>
        <h1>Seleccione la imagen sombreada que corresponda:</h1>
        <div class="localizaciones">
            <img src="/images/lamina1/Dd24.gif" alt="localizaciones correspondientes al centro y abajo"
                 class="img-thumbnail" id="Dd24" onclick="showTextThumbnail()">
            <div class="img_description">Imagen seleccionada</div>

            <img src="/images/lamina1/Dd32.gif" alt="localizaciones correspondientes al centro y abajo"
                 class="img-thumbnail" id="Dd32" onclick="showTextThumbnail()">
            <div class="img_description">Imagen seleccionada</div>

            <img src="/images/lamina1/Dd34.gif" alt="localizaciones correspondientes al centro y abajo"
                 class="img-thumbnail" id="Dd34" onclick="showTextThumbnail()">
            <div class="img_description3">Imagen seleccionada</div>

            <img src="/images/lamina1/Dd28-DdS28.gif" alt="localizaciones correspondientes al centro y abajo"
                 class="img-thumbnail" id="Dd28-DdS28" onclick="showTextThumbnail()">
            <div class="img_description4">Imagen seleccionada</div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <h3>Si ninguna imagen corresponde a lo que ve, haga click en este <a href="drawingpad">link</a> para dibujarla.</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about wrapping both `img` and `description` in a container `div` then apply css to the container div. Also use `display: inline-block` in this container to get the images to line up correctly.

Comment: do you want people to be able to select multiple images or just one?

Comment: @thehuijb originally they choose just one image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work you would want to add a container around each image, add a bit of css and change your javascript to interact with the container.

Here's an example of what you could do, keep in mind there are other solutions to this problem, this is just one to get you going.

```js
var elms = document.querySelectorAll(".img_container");

function showTextThumbnail(element) {
    elms.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    element.classList.add('active');
}

elms.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", () => showTextThumbnail(el), false);
});
```

```css
.img_container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /*para hover:*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.img_description {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 128, 68);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
.img_container.active > .img_description {
  display: block;
}
.localizaciones {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*//para hover:*/
  position: relative;
}

.localizacionHover {
  position: absolute;
}

.img-thumbnail:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="central-bottom" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Cerrar" class="close">X</a>
        <h1>Seleccione la imagen sombreada que corresponda:</h1>
        <div class="localizaciones">
            <div class="img_container">
                <img src="/images/lamina1/Dd24.gif" alt="localizaciones correspondientes al centro y abajo" class="img-thumbnail" id="Dd24">
                <div class="img_description">Imagen seleccionada</div>
            </div>
            <div class="img_container">
                <img src="/images/lamina1/Dd32.gif" alt="localizaciones correspondientes al centro y abajo" class="img-thumbnail" id="Dd32">
                <div class="img_description">Imagen seleccionada</div>
            </div>
            <div class="img_container">
                <img src="/images/lamina1/Dd34.gif" alt="localizaciones correspondientes al centro y abajo"
                 class="img-thumbnail" id="Dd34">
                <div class="img_description">Imagen seleccionada</div>
            </div>
            <div class="img_container">
                <img src="/images/lamina1/Dd28-DdS28.gif" alt="localizaciones correspondientes al centro y abajo" class="img-thumbnail" id="Dd28-DdS28">
                <div class="img_description">Imagen seleccionada</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3>Si ninguna imagen corresponde a lo que ve, haga click en este <a href="drawingpad">link</a> para dibujarla.</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```